# PL/SQL trigger to update another table(using primary keys) for insert on one table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Scenario is,

`TableA` schema:

```
 PK(col_1, col_2, col_3), col_4, col_5
 col_1 VARCHAR2(2)
 col_2 VARCHAR(16)
 col_3 VARCHAR(3)
 col_4 NUMBER
 col_5 NUMBER
```

`TableB` schema:

```
 PK(col_1, col_2, col_3), col_4, col_5, col_6
 col_1 VARCHAR2(2)
 col_2 VARCHAR(16)
 col_3 VARCHAR(3)
 col_4 NUMBER
 col_5 NUMBER
 col_6 CHAR(1)
 col_7 CHAR(1)
```

---

Trigger update on `TableB` for every row insert in `TableA`

Primary keys for TableA and TableB has same composite keys - PK(col_1, col_2, col_3).

First 5 columns of `TableA` & `TableB` are same.

---

Question:

In Oracle DB, How to use primary key values of `TableA` row to update corresponding row in `TableB`? in below code...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_tableA
  BEFORE INSERT ON TableA
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  UPDATE TableB
  SET col_6 = 'Y'
  SET col_7 = 'Y'
  WHERE <use primary keys of inserted record in TableA>;
END trigger_tableA;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `merge`.

```
create or replace trigger trigger_table1
  before insert on tablea
  for each row
begin
  merge into tableb b
  using tablea a
  on (    a.col1 = b.col1
      and a.col2 = b.col2
      and a.col3 = b.col3
     )
  when matched then update set
    b.col6 = 'Y',
    b.col7 = 'Y';
  where b.col1 = :new.col1
    and b.col2 = :new.col2
    and b.col3 = :new.col3;
end;
/
```

**[EDIT]** On a second thought, maybe your `update` attempt even makes more sense then my `merge`. Though, should be correctly written as

```
create or replace trigger trigger_table2
  before insert on tablea
  for each row
begin
  update tableb b set
    b.col6 = 'Y',
    b.col7 = 'Y'
  where b.col1 = :new.col1
    and b.col2 = :new.col2
    and b.col3 = :new.col3;
end;
/
```

**[EDIT #2]** If you want, you can *combine* different options within the same trigger. You'd use `IF-THEN-ELSE`, e.g.

```
create or replace trigger trigger_table2
  before insert or update or delete on tablea
  for each row
begin
  if inserting then
     update tableb b set
       b.col6 = 'Y',
       b.col7 = 'Y'
     where b.col1 = :new.col1
       and b.col2 = :new.col2
       and b.col3 = :new.col3;
  elsif updating then
     update tableb b set
       b.col6 = 'N',
       b.col7 = 'Y'
     where b.col1 = :new.col1
       and b.col2 = :new.col2
       and b.col3 = :new.col3;
  elsif deleting then
     update tableb b set
       b.col6 = 'N',
       b.col7 = 'N'
     where b.col1 = :new.col1
       and b.col2 = :new.col2
       and b.col3 = :new.col3;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: What does `a` , `b` & `:new` indicate? in this syntax

Comment: I think, now the syntax in this answer make sense

Comment: Sorry, missed to specify tables' **aliases** (that's what `a` and `b` represent; I fixed it). `:new` represents a **pseudorecord** - that's the way Oracle decided to distinguish new values from old (which are then referenced as `:old`). In this example, it is used to make sure that only appropriate row(s) get updated. Without WHERE clause, you'd update the whole table (and that's not what you want).

Comment: So, every ro insert in `tablea` ,  update on `tableb` occurs, with good performance, because we are using primary keys in `WHERE` clause. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I edited the answer and suggested another option: UPDATE. If I had to choose, I'd take UPDATE rather than MERGE in this case.

Comment: Instead of UPDATE, if it is DELETE, then it would be the same syntax. Correct me

Comment: Yes. Also, if you want, you can do both (or even more!) in the same trigger. Have a look at edited answer, I added another example.